# Does dot-slash ever behave differently than its ommission?

Tags: javascript, unix

This is more a question of curiosity.  In JavaScript and HTML, does dot-slash `./` (current working directory), ever solicit different behavior than the omission of it?

I'm assuming it does, otherwise it would never be used.  But I've never run into such a case.

For instance, in javascript:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
```

vs

```
var config = require('config.json');
```

are both relative and refer to the same file.  Any case in which it doesn't?

Comment: I can't come up with an example but suppose this: a function that load some modules. By specifying `./config.json` the function knows that have to look up only in the pwd. By not doing it, the function might start looking by predefined path inside some settings.

Comment: @PauloBu, oh totally! okay i've seen that. this should be the answer -- or at least one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it may depending on what environment you're running and what is handling the URL/filePath.

In your example, require is being used to look for a file path. When specifying the file path in `require` in node.js, for example, the script will actually look for the file name in a few locations if it is not found in the current directory, looking down a chain of directories for the file until it comes to a conclusive determination that the file doesn't exist in any of those locations. See more here: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

In this case, making the location explicit with `./` means node.js `require` is given explicit instructions on where to find the file and will not look anywhere else. And will return an error right away if it's not in the current dir.

However, with HTML, very typically the browser will only look in the same URL path as the HTML file that is making the file request, and so `<script src="file.js"></script>` will generally always yield the same results as `<script src="./file.js"></script>`. I can't think of an example where it wouldn't.

I can't say the same for client side javascript libraries, as it also depends on how these libraries will search for files. Using `require.js` on the client side, you can set up a fallback location to search for files if the current working directory doesn't have it: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths

So to answer, it depends on what functions/methods are interpreting your file path!